# Can't call static method from another class to main class

Tags: java, visual-studio, static

I'm  trying to run this code in Visual Studio Code where the main class calls a static method from another class, but I get an error.. The menu method calls the options method. I've tried it in Eclipse and it works well.. I don't know if it's a Visual Studio problem that I'm missing

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Interface.menu();   
    }
}
```

```
public class Interface {

    //Constructor
    public Interface(){
    }

    //Methods
    public static void menu(){...
        }

    public static void options(){...
    }
}
```

Error:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
        Interface.menu();
        ^
  symbol:   variable Interface
```

Comment: interface is a reserved keyword - I'm surprised the compiler will allow a class to be named Interface - either way a very bad practice as is overuse of static methods.

Comment: Are both in the same package/directory?